# ldap return variable

Tags: php, ldap, return-value

We are quite new here with LDAP and stuff and so far, all we seem to be able to do with and LDAP authentification is to get if the login/password is good or bad (Via LDAP bind() with php)

What we would like to do is, in the case of a good login, to get back a variable (for example, the user matricule) from the LDAP. Is this possible, and if it is, how?

Example from the PHP doc of the LDPA function:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Firstly, you are doing `or die()` after `ldap_connect()`, which makes your `if ($ldapconn)` pointless - if you get that far, it will always be true. Secondly, `ldap_connect()` will *always* be true, because it always returns an initialised resource, it doesn't actually communicate with the server until you `ldap_bind()` - it is the result of this that you really need to check. Thirdly, what? Is your question "How do I query the directory after I have connected"?

Comment: Exactly. We need to check if our User/Pass is valid (with the LDAP bind) and then, if valid, to get some more info from the directory

Comment: Well you need to use `ldap_read()`/`_search()`/`_list()` for that. You will need to know the base DN to be used for the data you want to get - what exactly are you trying to get? And what kind of LDAP server are you querying? AD or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Then the ldap_connect examples of the online php manual are wrong:

```
// Variables del servidor LDAP
$ldaphost = "ldap.example.com";  // servidor LDAP
$ldapport = 389;                 // puerto del servidor LDAP

// Conexión al servidor LDAP
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
           or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
```